# How can I execute a script on my dedicate server

Tags: ssh, script, python

I own a server (ftp.xxxxx.com) and i want to execute a script that sort files into directories. Here i am:
I write a simple script (script.py) that create a directorie and put in on my server (with Filezilla). I configure my file to be executable (705 or 715). When i try ftp.xxxxx.com/script.py, it reads the file, but doesn't execute it :(
So i tryed to execute it by ssh:
I connect myself via ssh to the server (with putty). I try a simple ls to be sure the file exists and it is. But when i try to execute script.py it says "No file or directorie of this type"
[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwSiL.png)
[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3lkY.png)
Can someone help me to execute this script please !

Comment: You are running a script named `/serveur2`, that is, `serveur2` in the root directory.  There is no such file; you have placed the file in a directory other than the root.  You can execute with the full path, something like `/home/eccitymo/serveur2` or explicitly specify the relative path to the current working directory `./serveur2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a script in the current directory (that is not in your PATH variable), you have to run it starting with `./`:

```
$ ./serveur2
```